# Dynamics 365: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a new custom activity in an existing assembly, it retrieves a record from an entity and copies that record again in the database with some little changes,
then I'm calling this custom activity in a workflow "after completing a task" it works normally and created the new record I wanted to be created, but when completing a different task using a different custom activity in the same assembly it throws the below error.

I tried to unregister the new custom activity and remove its calling from the workflow it throws the same error although the newly added activity is unregistered!!

error:

---

[Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin]
[46f6cf4c-14ae-4f1e-98a1-eae99a37e95c: ExecuteWorkflowWithInputArguments]
Sync workflow 'Tedata | Service Order | Technical Decision Taken' terminated with error 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #93D57568'
</s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Note: the activity inside this workflow ( 'Tedata | Service Order | Technical Decision Taken) is already existing and I didn't change it.

Comment: First, your question is not clear. Please define it clear so that we can easily understand.
From your question it looks like your logic is running in loop complete but once you redefine your question it will give more clarity

Comment: the question is why when I unregistered a new custom activity the error of "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" still exists!!
@AnkUser

Answer (score 1):

the reason is I was registering the custom activity with isolation mode sandbox and one of the custom activity in the assembly using early bound.

so to avoid this error, I changed the code to be late-bound, Workflow started working fine in Sandbox mode as well or register the workflow to be isolation mode none